# how to mapping nested object configuration in yaml quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, configmap

how can i mapping application.yml to config file ?

here i have config in application.yml

```
games-config:
  config:
   -  variation-number: 6
       game-name: Match the shadow
       number-of-items: 5
   -  variation-number: 5
      game-name: Drag object to matching Basket
      number-of-items: 4
   -  variation-number: 5
      game-name: Re arrange the words
      number-of-items: 0
   -  variation-number: 5
```

and i try to mapping with this`

```
public class GameConfig {
    public Integer variationNumber;
    public String gameName;
    public Integer numberOfItems;
} 

@ConfigProperties(prefix = "games-config")
public class GamesListConfig {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "config")
    public List<GameConfig> config;
}
```

but i always got error like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qDbP.png)

Comment: Which Quarkus versions are you using? This should be supported in the last version.

Comment: i use quarkus version 1.10.5.Final

Comment: Can you try with 1.11.1.Final? It should work with that version.

Comment: Yes , I've tried and it's works!, Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires Quarkus version 1.11.x. Lists with complex object types were not supported in previous versions.

Comment: I have similar problem, I am using the latest quarkus and the config values in the list is always null. Even when I create a new instance for GamesListConfig, would it be possible for someone to give me a hint on where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please check this: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings